# How to get the currency information from this site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to bring to my google sheets the currency information from the site:

https://www.bbva.mx/personas/informacion-financiera-al-dia.html

I'm trying to use IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML but none of this is working for me

The information I need is this

[image: Information needed]

Any help on this please ???

Maybe using Apps scripts ?

---

Edit:
this is the code im using

```
function fetchData() {
  var url = 'https://www.bbva.mx/personas/informacion-financiera-al-dia.html';
  var dolarTable = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  Logger.log(dolarTable)
  var match = dolarTable.match(/Dólar(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(<\/tr>)/);
  var string = match[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, "");
  var dollar = string.search("\\$");
  var value = string.indexOf("$", dollar + 1);   
  var substrings = string.substring(value);

  var almostThere = substrings.substring(0).indexOf("<");
  var number = substrings.substring(0, almostThere);

  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets[0].getRange('A1').setValue(number);
}
```

getting this error
[image]

> Regular expression operation exceeded execution time limit (line 5, file "Code")

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the problem you're running into here is that while in Sheets, the IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML [Imports data from a table or list within an HTML page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en), the webpage you're trying to access is using active server scripts to generate the HTML content.

In Apps Script, there is a built-in [`UrlFetchApp` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/0url-fetch/url-fetch-app) which you can use to get HTML data - [it has its own limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), but allows you to get the data from a page into your script for usage.

The page you're trying to get uses a frame that contains an `.aspx` file, and it's this generated content that has the information you're trying to retrieve. Honestly, this solution is a little ad-hoc as I've used `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to get the data, then used regular expressions and built-in JavaScript string functions to get the information out as generically as I can:

```
function fetchData() {
  var dolarTable = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://bbv.infosel.com/bancomerindicators/indexv8.aspx').getContentText();
  var match = dolarTable.match(/Dólar(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(<\/tr>)/);
  var string = match[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, "");
  var dollar = string.search("\\$");
  var value = string.indexOf("$", dollar + 1);   
  var substrings = string.substring(value);

  var almostThere = substrings.substring(0).indexOf("<");
  var number = substrings.substring(0, almostThere);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1').setValue(number);
}
```

This will fetch the HTML data of the page, then reduce what you're looking for by substring filtering. I've kept it generic so as long as the structure of the page doesn't change too much, it should still work even if the value of the amount changes.

Comment: Use the inner `.aspx` page at `https://bbv.infosel.com/bancomerindicators/indexv8.aspx`. I've updated my answer with these additions.